# Background freezes weirdly in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background

My background is acting very weirdly sometimes. This only solution is to reboot. In fact the top left corner is displaying my whole original background and the rest is completely bugged.

I don't know what info to give you, I have a Dell XPS 13 2015, running ubuntu 14.04

Output of  lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0665
    Kernel driver in use: i915

Output of uname -a

Linux michael-XPS-13-9343 3.13.0-52-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 4 04:32:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thank you in advance for every ideas :)

[image: background problem]

Comment: Please add output of "lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2" to your question.

Comment: And also please add "uname -a" too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to upgrade kernel and your graphical stack to HWE of Ubuntu 14.04.2. Do it by running

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

And reboot.

Comment: I try that in a second, is'nt it risky ? It won't add any bugs or anything ? It's just that it's my main computer for work so I want to be sure to be able to work tomorrow morning :). Thank you

Comment: If you did not install linux-intel-graphics installer, it must be quite safe. Has upgraded a lot of computers this way. But I cant give a 100% gurantee. But with that installer it won't just upgrade.

Comment: My computer is fine, the normal background came back after reboot but I can't tell you that the problem is fixed, as it happened only sometimes. I will keep you updated in case it comes back. Thanks !

Comment: If you have no such problems for a while, then mark it as solved.

Comment: I will do it, and btw, graphical animations, scrolling, etc seem to be working much more smoothly and rapidly, so I believe there was actually a problem, thanks :)